# simple way te to compute rgb buffer from I420 frame ffmpeg

Tags: c++, image, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compute directly rgb buffer from avframe. Something is going wrong since the obtained image is wrong. Extracting grey image from AVFrame->data[0] is working fine. However I'm not able to extract colored image

```
inline void YCrCb_to_RGB8(int Y, int Cr, int Cb, int& R, int& G, int& B){

   R = (int)(Y + 1.402 *(Cr - 128));
   G = (int)(Y - 0.344136*(Cb-128) -0.71414*(Cr-128));
   B = (int)(Y + 1.772 *(Cb-128));

   if (R < 0) R = 0; else if (R > 255) R = 255;
   if (G < 0) G = 0; else if (G > 255) G = 255;
   if (B < 0) B = 0; else if (B > 255) B = 255;
}

int getRGB8buffer(AVFrame* pFrame, byte* buffer){

   const int width = pFrame->width, height = pFrame->height;
   int Y, Cr, Cb;
   int R, G, B;

   int pixel = 0;
   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {

        Y = pFrame->data[0][x + y * width];
        Cr = pFrame->data[1][x / 2 + ((int)(y / 2)) * pFrame->linesize[1]];
        Cb = pFrame->data[2][x / 2 + ((int)(y / 2)) * pFrame->linesize[2]];

        YCrCb_to_RGB8(Y, Cr, Cb, R, G, B);
        buffer[pixel * 3 + 0] = R;
        buffer[pixel * 3 + 1] = G;
        buffer[pixel * 3 + 2] = B;
        pixel++;
    }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

When I save the obtained image as ppm using

```
int save_RGB_frame(unsigned char* buf, int wrap, int xsize,int ysize, const char* filename){

   FILE* f;
   int i;
   f = fopen(filename, "w");
   // portable ppm format -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example
   fprintf(f, "P6\n%d %d\n%d\n", xsize, ysize, 255);

   // writing line by line
   for (i = 0; i < ysize; i++)
      fwrite(buf + i * wrap, 1, xsize*3, f);
   fclose(f);

   return 0;
 }
```

The resulting image is wrong
link the the resulting image https://github.com/hacenesh/ffmpeg_question/blob/main/img_2028144.ppm

Comment: It's not that bad. You can fix it for them.

Comment: I've implemented a handful of RGB/YUV converters before. Your code looks fine.  Can you share a sample image that is corrupted after converting to RGB? You can paste and image directly into the question and it will automatically include it via imgur for you.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `pFrame->linesize[1] == pFrame->width/2` ?.  Because my first thought was that it should be `Cr = pFrame->data[1][x / 2 + (y/2)*(width/2)];`

Comment: thank you for your help. Yes pFrame->linesize[1] == pFrame->width/2. the website is note accepting .ppm as image so a added I link to it through github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is using `fopen(filename, "w")` instead of `f = fopen(filename, "wb")`.

In Windows OS, there is an important distinction between **binary file** and text file.
The default `"w"` option, opens the file as text file.
When writing to text file, each new line character `\n` is converted to two characters `\r\n`.
The additional characters messes up the entire structure of the image.
Note: In case you are using Linux, `"wb"` and `"w"` supposed to be the same.

Corrected code of `save_RGB_frame`:

```
int save_RGB_frame(unsigned char* buf, int wrap, int xsize, int ysize, const char* filename)
{
    FILE* f;
    int i;
    //f = fopen(filename, "w");
    f = fopen(filename, "wb"); //In Windows OS, we must use "wb" for opening a binary file (by default "w" applies text file).
    // portable ppm format -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example
    fprintf(f, "P6\n%d %d\n%d\n", xsize, ysize, 255);

    // writing line by line
    for (i = 0; i < ysize; i++)
        fwrite(buf + i * wrap, 1, xsize*3, f);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Saving to PPM image file:

```
save_RGB_frame(buffer, width*3, width, height, "img.ppm");
```

---

Issues in `getRGB8buffer`:
The orders of the planes of YUV420p format is `Y` then `U` then `V`.
`U` applies `Cb` and `V` applies `Cr`, so the order is: `Y`, `Cb`, `Cr`.

Corrected code of `getRGB8buffer`:

```
int getRGB8buffer(const AVFrame* pFrame, byte* buffer)
{
    const int width = pFrame->width, height = pFrame->height;
    int Y, Cr, Cb;
    int R, G, B;

    int pixel = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            //YUV420p planes ordering is Y, Cb, Cr (not Y, Cr, Cb).
            //Y = pFrame->data[0][x + y * width];
            //Cr = pFrame->data[1][x / 2 + ((int)(y / 2)) * pFrame->linesize[1]];
            //Cb = pFrame->data[2][x / 2 + ((int)(y / 2)) * pFrame->linesize[2]];
            Y = pFrame->data[0][x + y * pFrame->linesize[0]];   //Using pFrame->linesize[0] is prefered.
            Cb = pFrame->data[1][x / 2 + ((int)(y / 2)) * pFrame->linesize[1]];
            Cr = pFrame->data[2][x / 2 + ((int)(y / 2)) * pFrame->linesize[2]];

            YCrCb_to_RGB8(Y, Cr, Cb, R, G, B);
            buffer[pixel * 3 + 0] = R;
            buffer[pixel * 3 + 1] = G;
            buffer[pixel * 3 + 2] = B;
            pixel++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Issues in `YCrCb_to_RGB8`:
The conversion formula in your question applies JPEG conversion formula.
The default conversion formula used by FFmpeg applies BT.601 "limited range" conversion formula.
In "limited range", Y range is [16, 235] opposed to "full range" [0, 255].
Using "limited range" ("TV range") is much more common compared to "full range" (PC range / JPEG range).
[BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601) may be less common than [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) for HD videos, but BT.601 is FFmpeg default conversion (we are going to stick with BT.601).
Note: The conversion formula we are using here is the same as MATLAB function [ycbcr2rgb](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ycbcr2rgb.html).

```
inline void YCrCb_to_RGB8(int Y, int Cr, int Cb, int& R, int& G, int& B)
{
    //Subtract offsets and cast to double.
    //Subtractin 16 from Y assuems "limited range" YCbCr format where Y range is [16, 235] (oppused to "full range" whenre Y range is [0, 255]).
    double y = (double)(Y - 16);
    double u = (double)(Cb - 128);
    double v = (double)(Cr - 128);

    //The folloiwng conversion applies BT.601 "limited range" conversion formula.
    //Getting the same results as MATLAB function ycbcr2rgb.
    //BT.601 "limited range" is also the default conversion used by FFmpeg.
    R = (int)std::round(1.1644*y + 1.5960*v);
    G = (int)std::round(1.1644*y - 0.3918*u - 0.8130*v);
    B = (int)std::round(1.1644*y + 2.0172*u);

    R = std::max(std::min(R, 255), 0);
    G = std::max(std::min(G, 255), 0);
    B = std::max(std::min(B, 255), 0);
}
```